# Calling all number sequence lovers!

Tags: knowledge, number-sequence

What number follows in this sequence

> 93 1 855 45 593 500 241 ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I see a pattern:

> [Country calling codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes)
>  93 = AF **A**fghanistan
>  1 = BB **B**arbados, BM Bermuda, BS the Bahamas (and the entire USA)
>  855 = KH **C**ambodia
>  45 = DK **D**enmark
>  593 = EC **E**cuador
>  500 = FK **F**alkland Islands (and South Georgia)
>  241 = GA **G**abon

so the next number is

> 852 = HK **H**ong Kong? or maybe 504 = HN **H**onduras?